# Display all combination of coins (quarter, dime, nickel, penny) equal to X

Tags: java

Write a program that asks user to enter a dollar amount X. Display all combination of coins (quarter, dime, nickel, penny) equal to X. Enter dollar amount $: 1.2 4 quarter, 2 dime, 0 nickel, 0 penny 3 quarter, 4 dime, 1 nickel, 0 penny ......

```
package p1;

public class Combination {

    public static void findCombination(Double value){

        int totalCents = (int) (value*100);

        int aq = totalCents/25;
        int ad = totalCents/10;
        int an = totalCents/5;
        int ap = totalCents;

        for(int q=0; q<= aq; q++){

            for(int d=0; d<= ad; d++){

                for(int n=0;n<= an; n++){

                    for(int p=0;p<=ap; p++){

                        if(((q*25) + (d*10) + (n*5) + p ) == totalCents){

                            System.out.println("Q: "+q+" D: "+d+" N: "+n+" P: "+p );

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any more optimized solution than this, I couldn't think of one.

Comment: If your code works, you can post it to CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This type of thing falls within the type of problem that can be optimized through Dynamic Programming to reduce the overlapping work so it only gets done once. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming .

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the maximum value used in the for loop's boolean's. And maybe have the order flipped.

Something like:

```
int p=0, n=0, d=0, q=0;
for(p=0; p <= (totalcents-q*25-d*10-n*5) ; p++){

    for(n=0; (n*5) <= (totalcents-q*25-d*10) ; n++){

        for(d=0; (d*10) <= (totalcents-q*25) ; d++){

            for(q=0; (q*25) <= totalcents ; q++){

                if(((q*25) + (d*10) + (n*5) + p ) == totalCents){

                    System.out.println("Q: "+q+" D: "+d+" N: "+n+" P: "+p );

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested if it would speed up your code or not, but at very large values of X, it will likely be faster than going through all possible values of Q D N P as the maximum value is reduced.

Also this way you don't need:

```
int aq = totalCents/25;
int ad = totalCents/10;
int an = totalCents/5;
int ap = totalCents;
```

Comment: You are using q,d and n before they are defined. Maybe you made a typo?

Comment: But now you flipped the order so hard that you end up going back in time to supply values to expressions evaluated in the past.

Comment: I tried to think ahead of what the code will do when it runs with the order flipped, but it seems it will eventually do the same process, starting fast and slowing down when reaching the cents. I'm not 100% sure which order is faster, so you should test it out. But changing the max value for the for loops will definitly reduce runtime @harold .